# Getting next row into table but cant in dreamweaver

Tags: jquery, html

i have the following code to add new rows into table using Jquery.. i can get output while trying in fiddle but i cant get result while using Dreamweaver .,

can someone enlighten me where i got struck?
JQUERY:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$("#addrows").click(function () {
var newImageDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'add_div' + imagecounter);


newImageDiv.after().html('<table width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pdzn_tbl1" border="#729111 1px solid">'+
                        '<tr>'+
                        '<td style="padding:5px;" >'+'<input type="text" name="rollno<? $i ?>"  />' + '</td>' + '<td style="padding:5px;">'+ '<input type="text" name="firstname<? $i ?>" />'+'</td>'+'<td style="padding:5px;">'+'<input type="text" name="lastname<? $i ?>" />'+'</td>'+'</tr>'+'</table>');

                        newImageDiv.appendTo("#addgroup");


});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<h3> Adding Next Rows </h3>
<div class="common" style="width:1040px; -overflow-x:scroll; padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;" >
<table id="maintable" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pdzn_tbl1" border="#729111 1px solid"  >
<tr>    <th align="center"> Roll No </th>
        <th align="center"> First Name </th>
        <th align="center"> Last Name </th>
</tr>
<?php
$t_row=3;
for($i=1;$i<=$t_row;$i++) 
        {
        ?>
<tr id="rows">

<div style="padding-left: 5px"> 

<td style="padding:5px;" > <input type="text" name="rollno<? $i ?>"  /> </td>
<td style="padding:5px;"> <input type="text" name="firstname<? $i ?>" /> </td>
<td style="padding:5px;"> <input type="text" name="lastname<? $i ?>" /> </td>
</div>
</tr>

<? } ?>

<div id="add_div1"> </div>
 <table>
<div id="addgroup"> 
</div>
&nbsp; 
<br />
<input type="button" name="add" value="+Add" id="addrows" style="color:#3300FF; font-size:16px; " />
                <input type="hidden" id="hiddenprice" name="hiddenprice" value="3"/> </table>
</div>
</div>
```

my jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4KrwY/49/

Comment: what error you getting ?? check your browser console ? maybe  Jquery lib are not loaded ur page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import Jquery lib like this, and also you are missing
 script close tag

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
```

As it work in jsfiddle and if you copy paste same it has to work, or may be Jquery lib are not getting load,

Simple test try below code and see whether you getting this alert ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function(){
           alert("testing"); 
           // your awesome code here 
           // put your  here insdie document ready
         var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
        $("#addrows").click(function () {
          if (document.getElementById("hiddenprice").value == "") {
            imagecounter = 4;
         } else {
           imagecounter = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hiddenprice").value) + 1;
         }

        var newImageDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr("id", 'add_div' + imagecounter);
        newImageDiv.after().html('<table width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pdzn_tbl1" border="#729111 1px solid">' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td style="padding:5px;" >' + '<input type="text" name="rollno<? $i ?>"  />' + '</td>' + '<td style="padding:5px;">' + '<input type="text" name="firstname<? $i ?>" />' + '</td>' + '<td style="padding:5px;">' + '<input type="text" name="lastname<? $i ?>" />' + '</td>' + '</tr>' + '</table>');
       newImageDiv.appendTo("#addgroup");
       document.getElementById("hiddenprice").value = imagecounter;
       imagecounter++;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: ya i'd try this already but no effect., on clicking add button new rows not added in my table,. anything else?

Comment: what error you getting in you browser console ? do paste here

Comment: on click button function put an alert msg check whether you getting alert if not then jquery lib not loaded ,

Comment: yes you are right .. i dint get alert box on button click ..jquery lib not loading.. but i can get tis  testing alert on document loading..what's the solution for this?

Comment: put your script inside head tag section and your function inside `$(document).ready(function(){ // your code });`

Comment: hey you really blew my thoughts .. its working,, thank's a lot ,.

Comment: @user2720205: Happy coding, one suggestion in future append only tr for adding single row, not whole table , further you will face difficulties while retrieving values

Comment: oh sure.. u gave me fascinating answer.. thanks a lot once again i ll keep ur words mind..